# Problem with operator precedence

Tags: c, operator-precedence, turbo-c

The O/p comes out to be x=2,y=1,z=1 which doesnt agree with the operator precedence. I was running this on Turbo c++ compiler:

```
void main()
{
    int x,y,z,q;
    x=y=z=1;
    q=++x || ++y && ++z;
    printf("x=%d y=%d z=%d",x,y,z);
}
```

Comment: That's the correct result. If you care to explain why you expected something different, we may be able to tell you where your error is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Operator precedence does not in any way determine the order in which the operators are executed. Operator precedence only defines the grouping between operators and their operands. In your case, operator precedence says that the expression

```
q = ++x || ++y && ++z
```

is grouped as

```
q = ((++x) || ((++y) && (++z)))
```

The rest has absolutely nothing to do with operator precedence at all.

The rest is determined by the semantics of each specific operator. The top-level operator in this case is `||`. The specific property of `||` operator is that it always evaluates its left-hand side first. And if the left-hand size turns out to be non-zero, then it does not even attempt to evaluate the right-hand side.

This is exactly what happens in your case. The left-hand side is `++x` and it evaluates to a non-zero value. This means that your whole expression with the given initial values is functionally equivalent to a mere

```
q = (++x != 0)
```

The right-hand side of `||` operator is not even touched.

Comment: what abt operator precedence.&& has more precedence than ||. so the expression should be grouped as
q=(++x || ++y) && (++z).
why doesnt this happen and || gets more precedence.

Comment: @ramana: Er... You got it backwards somehow. Precedence, informally, speaking is the *ability of grab operands*. When you say `a || b && c`, the `&&` has higher precedence, meaning that it will be the first to grab its operands: `a || (b && c)`. I.e. `b` belongs to `&&` (and not to `||`) because `&&` has higher precedence. The `||` has lower precedence, so it takes what's left after `&&`. Of course, the `||` will be executed first in this case. But there's nothing unusual it in. As I said above, precedence is not related to the order of evaluation in any way.

Comment: thanx a lot andrey.its a great conceptual mistake.thnx for the crctn.

Answer (score 9):

Actually the result is in complete accordance with standard C. The logical or operator (`||`) short circuits after `++x` because it evaluates to a non-zero number, so the rest of them are ignored.

So starting at `x=1`, `y=1`, `z=1`, after the short circuit, you get `x=2`, `y=1`, `z=1`.

Comment: You're correct about the reasoning, but that is `logical or` not `bitwise or`. Bitwise or is `|` and doesn't use short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: According to the C99 standard, the operator '`|`' is the bitwise OR operator; the operator '`||`' is the logical OR operator.

Comment: You are correct of course, my bad.

Answer (score 5):

```
x=y=z=1;
```

Makes all the variables = 1

```
q=++x || ++y && ++z;
```

Since `++x` makes it = 2 and since it is not zero it stops checking the other conditions because the first one is `true`.

Thus, `x=2`, and `y and z = 1`

Comment: what abt operator precedence.&& has more precedence than ||. so the expression should be grouped as
q=(++x || ++y) && (++z).
why doesnt this happen and || gets more precedence.

Answer (score 0):

Logical `&&` (`AND`) and `||` (`OR`) operators are subject to Short-Circuit.

"Logical operators guarantee evaluation of their operands from left to right. However, they evaluate the smallest number of operands needed to determine the result of the expression. This is called "short-circuit" evaluation."

Thus, for logical operators always evaluated as (no matter `||` or `&&`) left to right.
And as previously mentioned, precedence here only determines who takes who.
Then left to right rule;

```
q = ++x || ++y && ++z;

//ok, lets play by rule, lets see who takes who:
//first pass ++ is badass here (has highest precedence)
//q = (++x) || (++y) && (++z)

//second pass &&'s turn
//q = (++x) || ((++y) && (++z))

//done, let's do left to right evaluation
q = (++x) || rest..
q = (true)|| whatever..
```

hope that helps more clear.