# Operator precedence in C

Tags: c, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why "++x || ++y && ++z" calculate "++x" firstly ? however,Operator "&&" is higher than "||"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700352/why-x-y-z-calculate-x-firstly-however-operator-is-higher)

The following program does not seem to work as expected. '&&' is to have higher precendence than '||', so the actual output is confusing. Can anyone explain the o/p please?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;

    x = y = z = 1;

    x++ || ++y && z++;

    printf("%d %d %d\n", x, y, z);

    return 0;
}
```

The actual output is: 2 1 1

TIA.

Comment: Another one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212482/problem-with-operator-precedence

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Precedence and order of evaluation have **no relation whatsoever**.

`&&` having higher precedence than `||` means simply that the expression is interpreted as

```
x++ || (++y && z++);
```

Thus, the left-hand operand of `||` is evaluated first (required because there is a **sequence point** after it), and since it evaluates nonzero, the right-hand operand `(++y && z++)` is never evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

The confusing line is parsed as if it were:

```
x++ || (++y && z++);
```

Then this is evaluated left-to-right. Since `||` is a short-circuit evaluator, once it evaluates the left side, it knows that the entire expression will evaluate to a true value, so it stops. Thus, `x` gets incremented and `y` and `z` are not touched.

Answer (score 1):

The operator precedence rules mean the expression is treated as if it were written:

```
x++ || (++y && z++);
```

Since `x++` is true, the RHS of the `||` expression is not evaluated at all - hence the result you see.