# Why lower precedence operator executes first?

Tags: c, operator-precedence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with operator precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212482/problem-with-operator-precedence)

we know that [precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++) of prefix is greater than "LOGICAL AND" (`&&`) and precedence of "LOGICAL AND" is greater than "LOGICAL OR" (`||`).

[Below program](http://ideone.com/DG22i) seems to violate it:

```
int main()

{
    int i=-3,j=2,k=0,m;
    m=++i||++j&&++k;
    printf("%d %d %d %d",i,j,k,m);
    return 0;
}
```

If precedence of `++` is more than `&&` and `||` then all prefix should execute first. After this `i=-2,j=3,k=1` and then `&&` will execute first.
why output shows : `-2 2 0 1` ?

The behavior of the program is also same on ubuntu v12.04.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `&&` and `||` operators are "short-circuiting".  That is, if the value on the left is FALSE for `&&` or TRUE for `||` then the expression on the right is not executed (since it's not needed to determine the value of the overall expression).

Comment: what about the precedence of ++ .

Comment: precedence affects what the operators apply to.  It has no effect on the order in which they are executed.

Comment: @aakasha -- You're confusing precedence and associativity.

Answer (score 2):

It's correct because Short-circuiting definition.

```
m = ++i||++j&&++k
```

First, left part ++i is always TRUE so now i is -2 and it doesn't execute the right part of expression, the value of j,k don't change.