# increment/decrement and output stream operator precedence in c++

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

Why the following code snippet output is `0 6 20 42 72 110` not `0 4 16 36 64 100`?

```
for(int i=0;i<11;i++){
    cout<< i * i++ <<" ";
}
```

According to [C++ Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) Suffix/postfix increment and decrement has higher precedence than multiplication which means that "i" will be incremented before multiplication.

Edit:
According to [Problem with operator precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212482/problem-with-operator-precedence) question, they said that Operator precedence does not in any way determine the order in which the operators are executed. Operator precedence only defines the grouping between operators and their operands, So how can `cout<< i * i++ <<" ";` will be grouped?

Comment: The cppreference page you linked explains that precedence is orthogonal to order of evaluation and gives a link to [the page with the OOE rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order). In fact, it has a very similar example, with addition instead of multiplication.

Comment: Unless this is C++17, `i * i++` is undefined and your program not a C++ program.

Comment: real dupe: [Operator Precedence vs Order of Evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473107/operator-precedence-vs-order-of-evaluation)

Comment: @molbdnilo, It's still undefined in C++17.

Comment: @molbdnilo Why this snippet is't c++, This is the complete program `#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
 for(int i=0;i<11;i++){
  cout<< i * i++ <<" ";
 }
 return 0;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of evaluation of the operands in `i * i++` is not guaranteed. You expect it to be left-to-right but your compiler is implementing it right-to-left. This means the increment happens before it evaluates the left-hand side `i`, meaning it prints `1 * 0`, `3 * 2`, `5 * 4` etc.